# Adding a Entity Reference in a Drupal 7 Theme

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming

I'm working on a custom theme for a Drupal site (7) and I need to print out an entity reference. I would like it to print out as a linked page title. Here's what I have, but it's not working. Sorry, I'm pretty new to this stuff.

```
<?php print $node->field_reflection['und'][0]['value'] ?>
```

Comment: `<?php print $node->field_reflection['und'][0]['value']; ?>` can you use  semi-column

Comment: First ensure you have right object into $node , second you need to pass variables to theme (custom theme function call or preprocess to add it into theme vars before output) 
And finaly , use function like field_get_items (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_get_items/7.x) to retrieve values from field